# Return different values to different functions

Tags: python, function, return

I have a function which returns say 2 values. Now, depending on which function this called from, I want to return these values. i.e, I have a function A, which returns values 'x' and 'y', if this function is called from function 'B', I want to return 'x' and if it is called from 'C', I want to return 'y'. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far, if not here's a tip: look into functions and inheritance

Comment: Can you add code for what you are trying to explain?

Comment: run function with different arguments and use this value to return different results. Or create thee different functions and run different functions in different places. Function should always return the same result for the same arguments - and it doesn't matter where it is used.

Comment: The called function does not know anything about the context in which it was called, so you should pass a parameter to it to control execution instead.

Comment: This looks like you’re trying to subvert normal programming conventions. Why are you doing this? Having implicit context change the meaning of a statement makes the program difficult if not impossible to reason about. Time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.

Comment: create function which always returns both `x` and `y` and then in functions A, B, C decide which values to use.

Comment: @furas `random.random` does not fulfill your "rule".

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa  `random.random` is "exception in rule" :) But if you use the same `seed` then `random.random` should give the same result.

Comment: @furas True. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. A function that returns more than one value returns a tuple of the values. So while calling the function from A, you can easily assign a variable to the first element of the returned value through indexing. For instance, Lets say I have a function like this:

```
def function_A(x, y):
    return x, y #returns a tuple of x and y - (x, y)

def function_B():
    variable = function_A(2,3)[0] #The 2,3 arguments is just an example.
    # This gives you the first return value.

def function_C():
    variable = function_A(2,3)[1]
    # And this gives the second return value
```